# SQL - Join Three Tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 same table and the other one.

Table 1 (List) Inserts ;

```
    Name     
    ---------
    Product1 
    Product2 
    Product3 
    Product4 
    Product5 
    Product6 
    Product7 
    Product8 
    Product9
```

Table 2 (A) Inserts ;

```
    Name     | Count 
    ---------+-------
    Product1 |   5
    Product2 |   23
    Product4 |   16
    Product5 |   3
    Product8 |   1
```

Table 3 (B) Inserts ;

```
    Name     | Count 
    ---------+-------
    Product1 |   8
    Product3 |   11
    Product4 |   29
    Product5 |   15
    Product6 |   5
    Product8 |   23
```

and I want this ;

```
    Name     |    A    |    B
    ---------+---------+--------
    Product1 |    5    |    8
    Product2 |    23   |    0
    Product3 |    0    |    11
    Product4 |    16   |    29
    Product5 |    3    |    15
    Product6 |    0    |    5
    Product7 |    0    |    0
    Product8 |    1    |    23
    Product9 |    0    |    0
```

The query must be include all items in List.Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `LEFT JOIN` `List` to `A` and `B`:

```
SELECT l.Name, COALESCE(A.Count, 0) AS A, COALESCE(B.Count, 0) AS B
FROM List l
LEFT JOIN A ON A.Name = l.Name
LEFT JOIN B ON B.Name = l.Name
ORDER BY l.Name
```

Output:

```
Name        A   B
Product1    5   8
Product2    23  0
Product3    0   11
Product4    16  29
Product5    3   15
Product6    0   5
Product7    0   0
Product8    1   23
Product9    0   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/2)

Comment: if I have Product2 twice ; Product2-> Count 3 and Count 4. How I get sum of these counts ?

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN you would need to replace `COALESCE(A.Count, 0)` with `COALESCE(SUM(A.Count), 0)` (and the same for `B`) and add `GROUP BY l.Name`. See the updated demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/3

Comment: Bro if I added Product3 to TableA ; sum worked false . Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/4

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN sorry, wasn't thinking enough when I wrote the comment. You need to do the SUMs in derived tables to avoid duplication issues. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdKLkyaeEsi8bPcNPkUnTE/9

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of which DBMS you are using, and for future reference, please include that in your tags.

What you need, presumably, is a [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) 
And [`COALESCE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) takes the first `NON NULL` value

```
SELECT
    List.Name,
    COALESCE(a.count, 0) as A
    COALESCE(b.cout, 0) AS B

FROM
    List
        LEFT JOIN A ON List.Name = A.Name
        LEFT JOIN B ON List.Name = B.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is correlated subqueries:

```
select l.name,
       (select a.count
        from a
        where a.name = l.name
       ) as a,
       (select b.count
        from b
        where b.name = l.name
       ) as b
from list l;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `left join`:

```
select l.name,
       coalesce(a.count, 0) as a,
       coalesce(b.count, 0) as b
from list l left join
     a
     on a.name = l.name left join
     b
     on b.name = l.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can left join twice and use `coalesce()` to return `0` instead of `null` on unmatched records:

```
select 
    t1.name,
    coalesce(t2.count, 0) A,
    coalesce(t3.count, 0) B
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
left join table2 t3 on t1.name = t3.name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53b263beb4acdd6d1a4c7b5da76066e5)**:

```
name     |  A |  B
:------- | -: | -:
Product1 |  5 |  5
Product2 | 23 | 23
Product3 |  0 |  0
Product4 | 16 | 16
Product5 |  3 |  3
Product6 |  0 |  0
Product7 |  0 |  0
Product8 |  1 |  1
Product9 |  0 |  0
```